# How to export Jetty launch configurations out of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, jetty, environment-variables, rtc

I would like to export my Jetty launch configuration so that another eclipse's jetty can consume it and use it.  I have searched for the `.launch` file, but the file I found is only the result of setting the configurations, not the file that jetty reads to get its configurations.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229831/850475

**Exporting**:

Go to File > Export... > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations

In the dialog Jetty

Set the filename

**Importing**:

Go to File > Import... > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations

In the dialog select Jetty config

Set the filename