# Long running selenium tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I am running selenium tests with maven from jenkins and after running for 5 hours suddenly the tests stop working and following error
`The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called`

possible solution is to

- increase heap size using argline in maven however it is not supported since Java 8 another
- stop and restart the tests after few hours using jenkins or maven

What is best way to solve this problem?

Comment: avoid calling `System.exit` from the test suite that you are running. Have you ensured that none of your tests are returning or exiting unexpectedly?(maven doesn't interpret it)

Comment: Yes no tests are calling System.exit

Comment: Most probably there is some memory leak in your tests, slowly eating up all the memory till JVM crashes with OOM and dumps core and memory content. Try checking if there is anything eating memory when it should not be (e.g jconsole can be great help, default tool in JDK).

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33757854

Comment: @skandigraun all this is running on jenkins is there way to access jconsole in jenkins environment?