# JVM crashing when trying to run the tests by running `mvn test`

Tags: java, maven

Note: I am now aware of [The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi), I tried many of the solutions expressed there and none of them work or make any difference. I documented in this question what I tried and what happened. I don't believe this is a duplicate of that question, essentially, because no answer is accepted so we can't know what the cause behind the error really was and many different problems could cause this same error (not all crashes are the same).

I'm sort of reviving a project that was left in a broken state when I try to run the tests I get this error:

```
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

I can't go back to a known working state, because, well, I don't know when that happened and under what conditions.

This is the full output from the command:

```
> mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.example:projectxserver >--------------------
[INFO] Building projectxserver 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ projectxserver ---
[WARNING] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected: [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar, javax.inject-1.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
[WARNING] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\projectx\code\projectxserver\target\surefire-reports\2019-09-26T05-51-30_012-jvmRun1.dumpstream
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.748 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-26T05:51:32+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project projectxserver: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\projectx\code\projectxserver\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\oraclejdk\current\bin\java @C:\Users\pupeno\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12697495595942050464\surefireargs12476787747337053319 C:\Users\pupeno\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12697495595942050464 2019-09-26T05-51-30_012-jvmRun1 surefire10872047683044717734tmp surefire_013239801033816370074tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\oraclejdk\current\bin\java @C:\Users\pupeno\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12697495595942050464\surefireargs12476787747337053319 C:\Users\pupeno\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12697495595942050464 2019-09-26T05-51-30_012-jvmRun1 surefire10872047683044717734tmp surefire_013239801033816370074tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Not sure what information is relevant at this point, I'm happy to add whatever is needed to this question.

I tried OpenJDK 11, 12 and OracleJDK 12 as well as maven-sure-fire-plugin 2.22.2 and 3.0.0-M3. All give the same error.

I tried mvn clean and re-built. I tried removing my whole Maven repo, the `.m2` directory.

I also tried adding `<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>` as explained in [The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi) as well as `<argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>` just to make sure, but the error remained the same. I tried this only with Oracle JDK 12.

I also tried:

```
<configuration>
    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
</configuration>
```

just in case the other two parameters were relevant and it failed with this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project dashmanserver: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.StartupReportConfiguration -> [Help 1]
```

I tried adding `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>` but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi

Comment: @Martin'sRun: I just tried that, and it didn't solve it.

Comment: @rkosegi: I just tried that, and it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue; build works on one machine but on another machine it does not work.

Maven log on failing machine mentions a "dumpstream" file, e.g. \xxx\target\surefire-reports\2020-05-12T17-21-34_124.dumpstream

Peeking into that reveals:

```
    # Created at 2020-05-12T17:21:35.135
    Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LastName\/m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax/servlet-api\4/0/1\javax/servlet-api-4/0/1/jar;C:\Users\FirstName
```

So it turns out that I have "c:\users\FirstName LastName" as user directory, e.g. a space in my username, and I would assume that since servlet-api 4.0.1 does not have a module-info.class so there's some lookup in MANIFEST.MF I believe or whatever.

The other machine where the build is running fine is with a user directory that does not have a space in its name.

Weird thing is that it happens only when running tests, and it does not seem to matter whether useModulePath is true or false for maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This helped me narrow down where in the dump file to look for my problem which was similar to the original poster's problem.