# Crashed tests when building a Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I run a Maven `user-data` project integration tests, with the `mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2"` command, and they seem to pass all just fine, except that I get some crashed tests with the message: `The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?`
The same error also shows up for another project `user-rest` which is client of the above one. That leads me to think it may not be project related.

The full output console log shows:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default) @ user-data ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  07:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-08T17:52:22+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default) on project user-data: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?                                                                                           
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data && /home/stephane/.sdkman/candidates/java/13.0.2.hs-adpt/bin/java -jar /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/surefire/surefirebooter17442042042677513972.jar /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/surefire 2020-02-08T17-45-27_266-jvmRun1 surefire5026424780409372472tmp surefire_012665318530559224267tmp                                                                                                   
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.thalasoft.user.data.it.service.UserServiceTest
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:670)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:991)                                                                                                                  
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:837)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)                                                                                                                  
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

The `target/failsafe-reports/com.thalasoft.user.data.it.jpa.UserRepositoryTest.txt` file contains:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.thalasoft.user.data.it.jpa.UserRepositoryTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 263.924 s - in com.thalasoft.user.data.it.jpa.UserRepositoryTest
```

The `target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary.xml` file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<failsafe-summary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.o
rg/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/failsafe-summary.xsd" result="254" timeout="false">
    <completed>0</completed>
    <errors>0</errors>
    <failures>0</failures>
    <skipped>0</skipped>
    <failureMessage>org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly s
aying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data &amp;&amp; /home/stephane/.sdkman/candidates/java/13.0.2
.hs-adpt/bin/java -jar /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/surefire/surefirebooter17442042042677513972.jar /hom
e/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/surefire 2020-02-08T17-45-27_266-jvmRun1 surefire5026424780409372472tmp surefir
e_012665318530559224267tmp
Process Exit Code: 0
Crashed tests:
com.thalasoft.user.data.it.service.UserServiceTest
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:670)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:991)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:837)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
```

The directory contains:

```
11:24 $ ll target/failsafe-reports/
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane stephane   350 févr.  8 17:49 com.thalasoft.user.data.it.jpa.UserRepositoryTest.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane stephane  3501 févr.  8 17:52 failsafe-summary.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane stephane 23427 févr.  8 17:49 TEST-com.thalasoft.user.data.it.jpa.UserRepositoryTest.xml
```

I tried under the following JAVA versions:

```
12.0.2-open
11.0.6-open
13.0.2.j9-adpt
13.0.2.hs-adpt
```

and always get the same error.

UPDATE: The integration test that was crashing, does not crash if running only that test. The `mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2" -Dtest=UserServiceTest` command shows:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default) @ user-data ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ user-data ---
[INFO] Installing /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/target/user-data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/stephane/.m2/repository/com/thalasoft/user-data/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/user-data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-data/pom.xml to /home/stephane/.m2/repository/com/thalasoft/user-data/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/user-data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-09T11:41:02+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE: The same issue remains in the dependent `user-rest` project, that contains a dependency on the fixed `user-data` project. I tried adding the same plugin but it did not help. It had a `dumpstream` file which contains: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter`

```
✔ ~/dev/java/projects/user-rest [master|✚ 1] 
12:00 $ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
✔ ~/dev/java/projects/user-rest [master|✚ 1] 
12:06 $ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /home/stephane/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /home/stephane/.sdkman/candidates/java/13.0.2.hs-adpt
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.3.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Any chance the test you are running is calling `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to the most recent....

Comment: Seems related: [The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi)

Comment: @RonK No I'm not.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the following property:

```
<forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>120</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
```

Indeed the tests were so long there would be a time out in the fork.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in one of project. I fixed it by upgrading to the latest version of the `surefire` plugin and by disabling the class loader as suggested in the discussion https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/issues/90

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: First, I tried by upgrading the dependency to `3.0.0-M4` but the issue remained the same. Then I also added the `useSystemClassLoader` element with the false value, and the issue was indeed gone.

Comment: I now notice that, if that solved the issue in the `user-data` project, the same issue still is present on the dependent `user-rest` project that has a dependency on the former. I tried adding the same plugin but it did not help. It had a dumpstream file which contains: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter`

Comment: Update child module's pom XML also.

Comment: What do you mean ? I had already added the plugin into the dependent `user-rest` module. What else should I add in there ?

Comment: have you set the property to false in user-rest?

Comment: Yes of course I did the same configuration in the plugin.