# WSL2 console crashes due to too long log output

Tags: maven, ubuntu, logging, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I trigger a certain build (with mvn clean install) the build fails at some point with this exeption:
`org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?` I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi) question on stackoverflow and was able to build the projects with `mvn clean install > log-file.log`. The Log file has over 100.000 lines.

Now I wonder why my console isn't able to process the logs and if I can configure it to do so.

I run Ubuntu 20.04 in a WSL2 using zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally solved the Problem was to change the log level at certain points (ok, not myself but a coworker, after we realized others were getting the same error). Mostly I went to the `.*/test/resources/log4j2.xml` files and changed `<Root level="DEBUG">` to `<Root level="INFO">` or some even to `<Root level="WARN">`. There is still some excessive logging, but at least I can build the project now.