# Vm crash when to run mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven

I have try to run my application from overseas team, but when i check for running i got error like this... this application is use java spring boot. and running under java 11, maven 3.8.0

```
   [ERROR] ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
        [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe" ${jacoco.agent.ut.arg} org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter "C:\Users\aaaa aaa\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3957096500956153590" 2021-06-14T09-51-37_283-jvmRun1 surefire8079989548794399184tmp surefire_06128817655274274221tmp"
        [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
        [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
        [ERROR] ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
        [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe" ${jacoco.agent.ut.arg} org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter "C:\Users\aaaa aaaa\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3957096500956153590" 2021-06-14T09-51-37_283-jvmRun2 surefire9075339761046576372tmp surefire_216089768638282606168tmp"
        [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
        [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.awaitResultsDone(ForkStarter.java:511)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet(ForkStarter.java:458)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:299)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:247)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
```

i have try to search the solution like add junit dependency or increasing memory for running my java. but i still got an error like that. my question is how to fix this issue ?

here my plugins for in my pom.xml

```
  <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>aaa.aaaa.MainApp</mainClass>
                    <skip>${maven.packages.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin><groupId>com.spotify</groupId><artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId></plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <overwrite>false</overwrite>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency><groupId>mysql</groupId><artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId><version>8.0.15</version></dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi

Comment: SET JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1024m' XX:+UseLoopPredicate i have use this in my commandline