# Error when running JUnit Tests from DOS Command line

Tags: java, junit, junit4

My projects is running on a Windows 2008 Server.

My project source code sit in the following folders:

```
com.company.division.dao
com.company.division.entity
com.company.division.main
com.company.division.junit
```

My junit test class are in the folder C:\Sample\com\company\division\junit.
I am using JUnit 4.11

When I run this from Eclipse it runs fine.

I have tried the following from DOS command line:

First I cd C:\Sample\com\company\division\junit\

From C:\Sample\com\company\division\junit> where the compiled EventTests.class file exists I run:

```
java  -classpath "C:\Sample\lib\junit.jar;" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.company.division.junit.EventTests
```

OR

```
java  -cp "C:\Sample\lib\junit.jar;" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.company.division.junit.EventTests
```

OR

```
java  -cp ".;C:\Sample\lib\junit.jar;" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.company.division.junit.EventTests
```

But nothing seems to work. I get an exception:

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: com.company.division.junit.EventTests
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

### Edited - New update

So from one of the [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502518/eclipse-export-running-configuration/2502638)  I figured out what the command eclipse was using to run the unit tests. Eclipse was using javaw.exe, I replaced javaw with java.exe tool.
Here is the command,

```
C:\Java\64bit_Browser_Plugin\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath C:\working_dir\bin;C:\working_dir\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\ojdbc14.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\nzjdbc.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\junit.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-batch-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\mail.jar;C:\working_dir\lib\spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar;/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/167/1/.cp/;/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/166/1/.cp/ org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 54536 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.omnitracs.fra.junit.EventTests
```

I am still getting an exception:

```
Could not connect to:  : 54536
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.connect(Remote
TestRunner.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTest
Runner.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTes
tRunner.java:197)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including hamcrest-core.jar in the classpath.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install

Comment: I still get Could not find class: com.company.division.junit.EventTests Time:0 OK (0 tests)

Answer (score 1):

Changing directories to where your test is located is a mistake. The `java` program will start from the classpath you give it and assume the package directory structure starts from there, so if you are in `C:\Sample\com\company\division\junit\` and you give the java command `-cp = "."` then it will look for the class `com.company.division.junit.EventTests` in `C:\Sample\com\company\division\junit\com\company\division\junit\`.

Also if you don't include your classes in the classpath (your last example is the only one to include them) then the `java` exe won't find them.

You need to add the current directory to the classpath, first changing directories so that the top of the package structure is at your current directory:

```
cd c:\Sample
java -cp ".;lib\*.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.company.division.junit.EventTests
```

This way `.` points to where your packages are defined.

If you would rather use absolute paths then try

```
java -cp "C:\Sample;C:\Sample\lib\*.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.company.division.junit.EventTests
```

You can use the `*` as a wildcard to include multiple jars starting with jdk 6.

For the future, consider using the directory layout used by default in Maven. Keeping tests separate from code is typically a good thing. I wonder if part of this problem isn't that test-only dependencies are located in a different spot than other libraries.

Right-click on your project in Eclipse and find the menu `Build Path -> Configure Build Path`, and make sure you know where Eclipse is getting these jars from.

Comment: Still no luck get the same error. I will try to setup a Maven.

Comment: @Ram what error are you getting? since this works in eclipse you have the jars locally, it's just a matter of finding where they are adding them to the java classpath.

Comment: JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: com.company.division.junit.EventTests

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)

Comment: @Ram: and what command did you execute to get this? did you try the absolute-path version i added here?

Comment: @Ram: where are your classes being written to? maybe they're being written to a different directory than the source? (another thing you can get from looking at the Configure Build Path stuff in eclipse)