# Error when running Junit Test from Windows Command Line

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Back 3 months ago I asked a similar question:
[Error when running JUnit Tests from DOS Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198687/error-when-running-junit-tests-from-dos-command-line)

I haven't solved the problem yet so I simplified the process by trying to run a simple sample TestCase Class from my Windows DOS command line.

My TestCase Class is:

```
package Test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
public class TestCaseA 
{
      @Before
       public void beforeMethod()
       {
           System.out.println("Before method..");
       }

       @Test
       public void JUnit4Test()
       {
          System.out.println("In test method");
       }

       @After
       public void afterMethod()
       {
          System.out.println("after method");
       }

}
```

I have a folder E:\Jenkins\Test\ where my compiled .class file exists and jUnit jar insdie E:\Jenkins\Test\lib\

See attached screen shots:

[image]

[image]

The command I am running to execute this from command line on a Windows Server MS DOS prompt is:

```
1. I Change Directory into E:\Jenkins\Test
2. E:\Jenkins\Test>java -cp E:\Jenkins\Test\junit-4.10.jar;Test\TestCaseA.class; org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test.TestCaseA
```

The output:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: Test.TestCaseA

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)
```

[image]

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Does it work if CP has `...;*E:\Jenkins\*Test\TestCaseA.class`? (Asterisks to highlight)

Comment: E:\Jenkins\Test>java -cp E:\Jenkins\Test\lib\junit-4.10.jar;E:\Jenkins\Test\TestCaseA.class; org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test.TestCaseA I think this is what you meant. No this throws the same error @AlexR

Comment: Okay last guess. What happens if you jar the .class files and add the .jar to the cp?

Comment: This looks like a classpath issue. For a package _Test_ with a class file _X:\foo\Test\TestCaseA.class_ the directory you should include in the classpath is `X:\foo`

Comment: @McDowell - Yes that worked! Can you add that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: E:\Jenkins\Test>java -cp E:\Jenkins\Test\lib\junit-4.10.jar;E:\Jenkins\;E:\Jenkins\Test\TestCaseA.class; org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test.TestCaseA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classpath issue. For a package *Test* with a class file *X:\foo\Test\TestCaseA.class* the directory you should include in the classpath is `X:\foo`

```
>java -cp E:\Jenkins\Test\lib\junit-4.10.jar;E:\Jenkins\ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test.TestCaseA
```

Comment: Please read this link on how to include multiple jars https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html