# JVM crash by running jar file but run project in eclipse is good

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm, bridj

I'm running into JVM crash when execute a runnable jar .But the project runs/debug without issues in eclipse. Any one can help a introduction how to trace where is the issue happening? Thanks.

Following are JVM core dump information:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=11671, tid=140603807495936
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-mockbuild_2015_01_21_05_53-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.4
# Distribution: Built on CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)  (Wed Jan 21 05:53:48 UTC 2015)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fe0d0021800):  JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11684, stack(0x00007fe0df7ff000,0x00007fe0e0000000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fe11856c070, RBX=0x00007fe0dfffe950, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x00007fe0dfffe9f0
RSP=0x00007fe0dfffe948, RBP=0x00007fe0d0009070, RSI=0x00007fe0dfffe950, RDI=0x00007fe1183c2440
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x00007fe11dea8c80, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x00007fe0dfffea50, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007fe0dfffe9f0, R15=0x00007fe1186b07e0
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fe0dfffe948)
0x00007fe0dfffe948:   00007fe0f4645ad2 3131393035313032
0x00007fe0dfffe958:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe968:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe978:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe988:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe998:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9a8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9b8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9c8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9d8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9e8:   00007fe11e750000 3a50544300000000
0x00007fe0dfffe9f8:   726f727245206f4e 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea38:   0000000000000000 00007f0000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea48:   00007fe1186b07e0 0000000000981003
0x00007fe0dfffea58:   00007fe0f48b7b60 00007fe0d0006f99
0x00007fe0dfffea68:   00007fe0d0006f99 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffea88:   00007fe0dfffead0 00007fe0d0009070
0x00007fe0dfffea98:   00007fe1186b07e0 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeaa8:   00007fe0dfffedf0 00007fe1186b1aa8
0x00007fe0dfffeab8:   00007fe0f466c890 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeac8:   00007fe11832a218 3131393035313032
0x00007fe0dfffead8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeae8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeaf8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeb08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeb18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeb28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fe0dfffeb38:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000000000)
0xffffffffffffffe0:   

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007fe11856c070 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fe0dfffe950 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007fe0dfffe9f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
RSP=0x00007fe0dfffe948 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
RBP=0x00007fe0d0009070 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007fe0dfffe950 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
RDI=0x00007fe1183c2440 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fe11dea8c80: <offset 0x146c80> in /lib64/libc.so.6 at 0x00007fe11dd62000
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x00007fe0dfffea50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007fe0dfffe9f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe0d0021800
R15=0x00007fe1186b07e0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007fe0df7ff000,0x00007fe0e0000000],  sp=0x00007fe0dfffe948,  free space=8190k

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x00007fe0d0021800 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11684, stack(0x00007fe0df7ff000,0x00007fe0e0000000)]
  0x00007fe118130000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11681, stack(0x00007fe11174d000,0x00007fe11184e000)]
  0x00007fe11812e000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11680, stack(0x00007fe11184e000,0x00007fe11194f000)]
  0x00007fe11812b000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11679, stack(0x00007fe11194f000,0x00007fe111a50000)]
  0x00007fe118129000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11678, stack(0x00007fe111a50000,0x00007fe111b51000)]
  0x00007fe1180fd800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11677, stack(0x00007fe111b51000,0x00007fe111c52000)]
  0x00007fe1180fb800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11676, stack(0x00007fe111c52000,0x00007fe111d53000)]
  0x00007fe118009000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11672, stack(0x00007fe11e845000,0x00007fe11e946000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007fe1180f7000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007fe111d53000,0x00007fe111e54000] [id=11675]
  0x00007fe11813b000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007fe11164c000,0x00007fe11174d000] [id=11682]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 8704K, used 3488K [0x00000000f2200000, 0x00000000f3300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 7680K, 32% used [0x00000000f2200000,0x00000000f246c108,0x00000000f2980000)
  from space 1024K, 98% used [0x00000000f2980000,0x00000000f2a7c020,0x00000000f2a80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000f3200000,0x00000000f3200000,0x00000000f3300000)
 ParOldGen       total 19456K, used 2024K [0x00000000d6600000, 0x00000000d7900000, 0x00000000f2200000)
  object space 19456K, 10% used [0x00000000d6600000,0x00000000d67fa3b0,0x00000000d7900000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 6604K [0x00000000cc000000, 0x00000000cd500000, 0x00000000d6600000)
  object space 21504K, 30% used [0x00000000cc000000,0x00000000cc673228,0x00000000cd500000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007fe11481d000,0x00007fe1149be000] byte_map_base: 0x00007fe1141bd000

Polling page: 0x00007fe11e970000

Code Cache  [0x00007fe1149be000, 0x00007fe114c2e000, 0x00007fe1179be000)
 total_blobs=323 nmethods=67 adapters=209 free_code_cache=48634Kb largest_free_block=49788096

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 6.872 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000   64             java.lang.Character::isWhitespace (5 bytes)
Event: 6.874 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000 nmethod 64 0x00007fe114a3dcd0 code [0x00007fe114a3de20, 0x00007fe114a3deb8]
Event: 6.874 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000   65             java.lang.Character::isWhitespace (9 bytes)
Event: 6.876 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000 nmethod 65 0x00007fe114a3f350 code [0x00007fe114a3f4a0, 0x00007fe114a3f5d8]
Event: 6.876 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000   66             java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1::isWhitespace (23 bytes)
Event: 6.877 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000 nmethod 66 0x00007fe114a3da50 code [0x00007fe114a3db80, 0x00007fe114a3dc18]
Event: 6.877 Thread 0x00007fe11812b000   67             sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser::parseIdentifier (115 bytes)
Event: 6.883 Thread 0x00007fe11812e000   68             java.lang.String::getChars (62 bytes)
Event: 6.886 Thread 0x00007fe11812e000 nmethod 68 0x00007fe114a3ef50 code [0x00007fe114a3f0a0, 0x00007fe114a3f1d8]
Event: 6.886 Thread 0x00007fe11812e000   69             java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (48 bytes)

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.689 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 8704K, used 7680K [0x00000000f2200000, 0x00000000f2b80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 7680K, 100% used [0x00000000f2200000,0x00000000f2980000,0x00000000f2980000)
  from space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000f2a80000,0x00000000f2a80000,0x00000000f2b80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000f2980000,0x00000000f2980000,0x00000000f2a80000)
 ParOldGen       total 19456K, used 0K [0x00000000d6600000, 0x00000000d7900000, 0x00000000f2200000)
  object space 19456K, 0% used [0x00000000d6600000,0x00000000d6600000,0x00000000d7900000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5646K [0x00000000cc000000, 0x00000000cd500000, 0x00000000d6600000)
  object space 21504K, 26% used [0x00000000cc000000,0x00000000cc5839d8,0x00000000cd500000)
Event: 0.697 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 8704K, used 1008K [0x00000000f2200000, 0x00000000f3300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 7680K, 0% used [0x00000000f2200000,0x00000000f2200000,0x00000000f2980000)
  from space 1024K, 98% used [0x00000000f2980000,0x00000000f2a7c020,0x00000000f2a80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000f3200000,0x00000000f3200000,0x00000000f3300000)
 ParOldGen       total 19456K, used 2024K [0x00000000d6600000, 0x00000000d7900000, 0x00000000f2200000)
  object space 19456K, 10% used [0x00000000d6600000,0x00000000d67fa3b0,0x00000000d7900000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5646K [0x00000000cc000000, 0x00000000cd500000, 0x00000000d6600000)
  object space 21504K, 26% used [0x00000000cc000000,0x00000000cc5839d8,0x00000000cd500000)
}

Deoptimization events (6 events):
Event: 0.328 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007fe114a210a0 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 0.328 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007fe114a210a0 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 0.328 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007fe114a210a0 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 0.377 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x00007fe114a267f4 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.457 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007fe114a23414 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.600 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Uncommon trap: reason=unreached action=reinterpret pc=0x00007fe114a30ccc method=java.util.HashMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 7

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.761 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f22eb580 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.804 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23cd4d8 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.805 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23d24f0 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.805 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23d2e78 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.808 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23ddf78 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.809 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23df900 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.809 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23e0738 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.810 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23e2400 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.810 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23e32f0 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636
Event: 0.810 Thread 0x00007fe118009000 Threw 0x00000000f23e43c0 at /builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:1636

Events (10 events):
Event: 6.857 loading class 0x00007fe0ec09cf60
Event: 6.857 loading class 0x00007fe0ec09cf60 done
Event: 6.857 loading class 0x00007fe1187e2040
Event: 6.857 loading class 0x00007fe1187e2040 done
Event: 6.859 loading class 0x00007fe1187e20a0
Event: 6.859 loading class 0x00007fe1187e20a0 done
Event: 6.875 loading class 0x00007fe11862abf0
Event: 6.875 loading class 0x00007fe11862abf0 done
Event: 6.876 loading class 0x00007fe1183718d0
Event: 6.876 loading class 0x00007fe1183718d0 done


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 137738402                          /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre-abrt/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 137738402                          /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre-abrt/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 137738402                          /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre-abrt/bin/java
023d6000-023f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
cc000000-cd500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
cd500000-d6600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d6600000-d7900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d7900000-f2200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f2200000-f3300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3300000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0d0000000-7fe0d0069000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0d0069000-7fe0d4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0d8000000-7fe0d8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0d8021000-7fe0dc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0deffe000-7fe0defff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0defff000-7fe0df7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11685]
7fe0df7ff000-7fe0df802000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0df802000-7fe0e0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11684]
7fe0e0000000-7fe0e0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0e0021000-7fe0e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0e4000000-7fe0e4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0e4021000-7fe0e8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0e8000000-7fe0e8147000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0e8147000-7fe0ec000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0ec000000-7fe0ec233000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0ec233000-7fe0f0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f0000000-7fe0f0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f0021000-7fe0f4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f43d8000-7fe0f456c000 r--s 00000000 fd:00 208754419                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thostmduserapi.so
7fe0f456c000-7fe0f46a4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 208754419                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thostmduserapi.so
7fe0f46a4000-7fe0f48a3000 ---p 00138000 fd:00 208754419                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thostmduserapi.so
7fe0f48a3000-7fe0f48b6000 rw-p 00137000 fd:00 208754419                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thostmduserapi.so
7fe0f48b6000-7fe0f49dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f49dd000-7fe0f4c1f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 208754418                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thosttraderapi.so
7fe0f4c1f000-7fe0f4e1f000 ---p 00242000 fd:00 208754418                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thosttraderapi.so
7fe0f4e1f000-7fe0f4e52000 rw-p 00242000 fd:00 208754418                  /tmp/CTPExtractedLibraries2742559170840408218/thosttraderapi.so
7fe0f4e52000-7fe0f4f7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f4f7d000-7fe0f4f98000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 4964676                    /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries8039313585574138907/libbridj.so
7fe0f4f98000-7fe0f5197000 ---p 0001b000 fd:00 4964676                    /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries8039313585574138907/libbridj.so
7fe0f5197000-7fe0f5198000 r--p 0001a000 fd:00 4964676                    /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries8039313585574138907/libbridj.so
7fe0f5198000-7fe0f5199000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 4964676                    /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries8039313585574138907/libbridj.so
7fe0f5199000-7fe0f51a9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69661847                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe0f51a9000-7fe0f53a8000 ---p 00010000 fd:00 69661847                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe0f53a8000-7fe0f53a9000 r--p 0000f000 fd:00 69661847                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe0f53a9000-7fe0f53aa000 rw-p 00010000 fd:00 69661847                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe0f53aa000-7fe0f58b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0f58b4000-7fe0f58d8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201495743                  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7fe0f58d8000-7fe0f5ad7000 ---p 00024000 fd:00 201495743                  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7fe0f5ad7000-7fe0f5ad8000 r--p 00023000 fd:00 201495743                  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7fe0f5ad8000-7fe0f5ad9000 rw-p 00024000 fd:00 201495743                  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7fe0f5ad9000-7fe0fc000000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 134829894                  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fe0fc000000-7fe0fc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe0fc021000-7fe100000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe100000000-7fe100021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe100021000-7fe104000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe104000000-7fe104021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe104021000-7fe108000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe108000000-7fe108021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe108021000-7fe10c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe10c000000-7fe10c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe10c021000-7fe110000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe110061000-7fe11006b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11006b000-7fe1100ca000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201495745                  /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
7fe1100ca000-7fe1102ca000 ---p 0005f000 fd:00 201495745                  /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
7fe1102ca000-7fe1102cb000 r--p 0005f000 fd:00 201495745                  /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
7fe1102cb000-7fe1102cc000 rw-p 00060000 fd:00 201495745                  /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
7fe1102cc000-7fe1102e2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201436551                  /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe1102e2000-7fe1104e2000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 201436551                  /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe1104e2000-7fe1104e3000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 201436551                  /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe1104e3000-7fe1104e4000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 201436551                  /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe1104e4000-7fe1104e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1104e6000-7fe110507000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201495757                  /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7fe110507000-7fe110707000 ---p 00021000 fd:00 201495757                  /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7fe110707000-7fe110708000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 201495757                  /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7fe110708000-7fe110709000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 201495757                  /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7fe110709000-7fe11070b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11070b000-7fe11070e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201633135                  /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11070e000-7fe11090d000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 201633135                  /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11090d000-7fe11090e000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 201633135                  /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11090e000-7fe11090f000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 201633135                  /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11090f000-7fe110916000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201633127                  /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe110916000-7fe110b15000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 201633127                  /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe110b15000-7fe110b16000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 201633127                  /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe110b16000-7fe110b17000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 201633127                  /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe110b17000-7fe110c48000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201633133                  /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe110c48000-7fe110e47000 ---p 00131000 fd:00 201633133                  /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe110e47000-7fe110e48000 r--p 00130000 fd:00 201633133                  /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe110e48000-7fe110e49000 rw-p 00131000 fd:00 201633133                  /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe110e49000-7fe110e4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe110e4a000-7fe110e98000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201633136                  /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe110e98000-7fe111098000 ---p 0004e000 fd:00 201633136                  /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe111098000-7fe111099000 r--p 0004e000 fd:00 201633136                  /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe111099000-7fe11109a000 rw-p 0004f000 fd:00 201633136                  /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11109a000-7fe111207000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201633131                  /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe111207000-7fe111406000 ---p 0016d000 fd:00 201633131                  /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe111406000-7fe11140a000 r--p 0016c000 fd:00 201633131                  /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11140a000-7fe11140c000 rw-p 00170000 fd:00 201633131                  /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.4000.0
7fe11140c000-7fe11140e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11140e000-7fe111415000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111415000-7fe111418000 r--s 00086000 fd:00 137738407                  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
7fe111418000-7fe11141b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11141b000-7fe111427000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111427000-7fe111434000 r--s 00075000 fd:00 4961306                    /tmp/jar_cache6625833399513660401.tmp (deleted)
7fe111434000-7fe11144b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69661846                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fe11144b000-7fe11164a000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 69661846                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fe11164a000-7fe11164b000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 69661846                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fe11164b000-7fe11164c000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 69661846                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fe11164c000-7fe11164d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11164d000-7fe11174d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11682]
7fe11174d000-7fe111750000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111750000-7fe11184e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11681]
7fe11184e000-7fe111851000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111851000-7fe11194f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11680]
7fe11194f000-7fe111952000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111952000-7fe111a50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11679]
7fe111a50000-7fe111a53000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111a53000-7fe111b51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11678]
7fe111b51000-7fe111b54000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111b54000-7fe111c52000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11677]
7fe111c52000-7fe111c55000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111c55000-7fe111d53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11676]
7fe111d53000-7fe111d54000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe111d54000-7fe1127a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11675]
7fe1127a6000-7fe112957000 r--s 03ed2000 fd:00 2189189                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar
7fe112957000-7fe1145c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1145c8000-7fe1145c9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1145c9000-7fe1146c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11674]
7fe1146c9000-7fe1146ca000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1146ca000-7fe1147d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:11673]
7fe1147d5000-7fe11481d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11481d000-7fe114828000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe114828000-7fe114870000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe114870000-7fe11487a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11487a000-7fe11494e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11494e000-7fe114957000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe114957000-7fe1149bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1149bd000-7fe1149be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1149be000-7fe114c2e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe114c2e000-7fe1179be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1179be000-7fe1179c6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69661853                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fe1179c6000-7fe117bc5000 ---p 00008000 fd:00 69661853                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fe117bc5000-7fe117bc6000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 69661853                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fe117bc6000-7fe117bc7000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 69661853                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fe117bc7000-7fe117bd2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201436541                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe117bd2000-7fe117dd1000 ---p 0000b000 fd:00 201436541                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe117dd1000-7fe117dd2000 r--p 0000a000 fd:00 201436541                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe117dd2000-7fe117dd3000 rw-p 0000b000 fd:00 201436541                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe117dd3000-7fe117dfe000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69661834                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fe117dfe000-7fe117ffd000 ---p 0002b000 fd:00 69661834                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fe117ffd000-7fe117ffe000 r--p 0002a000 fd:00 69661834                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fe117ffe000-7fe118000000 rw-p 0002b000 fd:00 69661834                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fe118000000-7fe1188d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe1188d0000-7fe11c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11c000000-7fe11c005000 r--s 0002a000 fd:00 4961300                    /tmp/jar_cache6781477567275170076.tmp (deleted)
7fe11c005000-7fe11c00f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11c00f000-7fe11c0e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe11c0e3000-7fe11c0f0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69661852                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fe11c0f0000-7fe11c2ef000 ---p 0000d000 fd:00 69661852                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fe11c2ef000-7fe11c2f1000 r--p 0000c000 fd:00 69661852                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fe11c2f1000-7fe11c2f2000 rw-p 0000e000 fd:00 69661852                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
```

Comment: do you use the same JVM or do you have different settings in eclipse ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I've just checked the JRE in eclipse and system default. They are same and my CentOS only have one default JRE 1.7.0.75.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest JRE from Oracle? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html for Java 7, or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html for Java 8? You can just download and upack them.

Comment: @sleske, how would it help if it can run from eclipse using the same JRE ?

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502518/eclipse-export-running-configuration) to export the java command run by eclipse and do run it from your cli see if that solves your issue

Comment: Thanks Frederic Henri's suggestion. I dropped the runable jar option and run as your comment successfully.