# Deploy Storm topology remotely using "storm jar" command on Windows

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am trying to deploy a storm topology to a remote machine using the storm jar command on Windows

```
storm jar jarName.jar mainClass
```

Here is what I have in my storm.yaml file:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "HostName"

nimbus.host: "HostName"
nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
```

But whenever I try to deploy, it always tries to deploy to my local machine.

**EDIT**

I tried putting the following configurations but it does not work:

```
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "HostName");
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT,6627);
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS,Arrays.asList(new String[]{"HostName"}));
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT,2181);
```

I also tried the -c option on the command line as:

```
storm -c nimbus.host=HostName jar jarName.jar mainClass
```

But it does not work; I get:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried placing the -c part at different places but nothing seems to work.

Also, I get

```
The field Config.NIMBUS_HOST is deprecated
```

when I set:

```
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "HostName");
```

I am using Storm version **0.10.0-beta**

**EDIT2**

Submitting works perfectly fine from IDE after I use

```
System.setProperty("storm.jar", "path to jar");
```

however, it does not work from command line.

**Edit3**

Thanks Matt for all your help. I was able to deploy the topology using the java command that eclipse executes. I am still unable to deploy using the storm jar command however. It complains that the topology already exists even though i dont see anything on the Storm UI. Also, when i deploy using Eclipse or the Java command from command line, the topology deploys successfully. How should i compare the difference between executing the java command and what the storm jar command is doing? i tried to echo the variables in this section of the cmd file

```
 if %storm-command% == jar (
    set STORM_OPTS=%STORM_CLIENT_OPTS% %STORM_OPTS% -Dstorm.jar=%2
    echo %STORM_OPTS%
    set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%2

    echo %CLASSPATH%

    set CLASS=%3
    set args=%4
    goto start
    :start
    shift
    if [%4] == [] goto done
    set args=%args% %4

    echo args: %args%

    goto start

    :done
    echo %args%
    set storm-command-arguments=%args%

  )
```

but i dont see anything unusual. Also, i see the following exception in the stacktrace

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:[SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:76688, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
```

notice

```
 topologies:[]
```

and then it complains that the topology  name exists

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:[SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:76688, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:342)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:226)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:271)

        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:157)

        at mainClass.submitTopology(mainClass.java:127)
        at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:57)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:[SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:76688, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.validate(ClusterSummary.java:515)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.
read(ClusterSummary.java:613)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.
read(ClusterSummary.java:549)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.read(ClusterSummary.java:473)

        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_
resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16546)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_
resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16531)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result.read(Nimbus.java:16470)
        at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)

        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:569)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:557)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:333)
        ... 5 more
```

finally, here is the entire stacktrace.

```
 X:\abc\xyz\target>ERROR StatusLogger Invalid URL C:/asd/ewt/apache-storm 0.10.0-beta/log4j2/cluster.xml java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
            at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getInputFromUri(ConfigurationFactory.java:296)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:395)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:254)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:419)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
            at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
            at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
            at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
            at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:35)
            at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:59)
            at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39)
            at mainClass.<clinit>(mainClass.java:32)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset!Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:76688, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
                at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:342)
                at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:226)
                at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:271)

                at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:157)

                at mainClass.submitTopology(mainClass.java:127)
                at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:57)
        Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:[SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:76688, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
                at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.validate(ClusterSummary.java:515)
                at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.
        read(ClusterSummary.java:613)
                at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.
        read(ClusterSummary.java:549)
                at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.read(ClusterSummary.java:473)

                at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_
        resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16546)
                at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_
        resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16531)
                at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result.read(Nimbus.java:16470)
                at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)

                at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:569)
                at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:557)
                at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:333)
                ... 5 more
```

and by the way what is that weird logging exception/error at the top of the stacktrace? could that have something to do with the weird behavior of storm jar command?

if i do

```
java -cp jarName.jar;C:\abc\asdasd\apache-storm-0.10.0-beta\lib\* mainClass
```

i get

```
513  [main] INFO  b.s.u.Utils - Using defaults.yaml from resources
582  [main] INFO  b.s.u.Utils - Using defaults.yaml from resources
590  [main] INFO  b.s.StormSubmitter - Generated ZooKeeper secret payload for MD
5-digest: -6100635753051151148:-8346710213172614614
591  [main] INFO  b.s.s.a.AuthUtils - Got AutoCreds []
599  [main] INFO  b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - The baseSleepTimeM
s [2000] the maxSleepTimeMs [60000] the maxRetries [5]
626  [main] INFO  b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry - The baseSleepTimeM
s [2000] the maxSleepTimeMs [60000] the maxRetries [5]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.protoc
ol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:SupervisorSummary(host:HostName, uptime_secs:83775, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:342)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:226)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:271)

        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:157)

        at com.rbccm.th2015.storm.SampleTopologyX.submitTopology(SampleTopologyX.java:127)
        at com.rbccm.th2015.storm.SampleTopologyX.main(SampleTopologyX.java:57)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset! Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:SupervisorSummary(host:HostName,uptime_secs:83775, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:7e4b13c5-05d5-4944-9566-d71f2c2de504, version:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.validate(ClusterSummary.java:515)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.read(ClusterSummary.java:613)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary$ClusterSummaryStandardScheme.read(ClusterSummary.java:549)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.read(ClusterSummary.java:473)

        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16546)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result$getClusterInfo_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:16531)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result.read(Nimbus.java:16470)
        at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)

        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:569)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:557)
        at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.topologyNameExists(StormSubmitter.java:333)
        ... 5 more
```

so its complaining about the same thing but via a different route. could this have something to do with my YAML? and what is this business about nimbus_uptime_secs?

**Final Edit**

ok, time to put this to rest. For now at least, it does not look like the sotrm jar command is suitable for windows. I can clearly see a difference in the command that storm.py tries to execute in Windows and the one that it tries to execute in Linux. Basically, the paths get screwed up in windows and that must be what's causing all of these weird exceptions.

Thanks Matt for all of your help and support. I really learned a lot.

Comment: works perfectly fine from ide after i use System.setProperty("storm.jar", "path to jar"); does not work from command line

Comment: it complains that the topology already exists. i do not see anything on the storm ui or on the storm list command. either on my local or on the remote machine

Comment: so i can enable local logging but where should i look for to find the cluster it is trying to upload to?

Comment: sorry, cant use chat from work. access denied to that location

Comment: also, i can see Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset!

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: have you run the storm jar command to deploy remotely ?

Comment: if possible, can you please share the exact command you ran and the configurations you had in your java code

Comment: would it be possible to run this using something like java -cp "somwhere" jar jarName

Comment: i have been trying to do that but it errors out after a no class def found error for some stork/kafka/BrokerHosts class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a topology via `storm jar` does only work on Linux (but not on Windows). The "storm" command is a Python script that assumes to run on Linux (Window is officially not supported by Storm).

However, "storm" command only starts a regular `java` command with appropriate setting. If a topology is submitted via an IDE, the IDE does the same thing. If you use Eclipse, you can extract the used configuration as described in [Eclipse: export running configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502518/eclipse-export-running-configuration)

Pay attention, that you need to set JVM argument `-Dstorm.jar=path\to\myJar.jar`; otherwise, `StormSubmitter` will not find the `jar` that should be submitted to Storm cluster.

After extracting the `java` command, it should allow you to submit a topology via command line on Windows. If extracting the command is not supported by your IDE, you can still put it together manually (even if this is a cumbersome solution).

It will be something like:

```
java -Dstorm.jar=yourJarFile.jar
     -classpath yourJarFile.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/storm-core/0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.21/kryo-2.21.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/reflectasm/1.07/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/clj-time/clj-time/0.8.0/clj-time-0.8.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/compojure/compojure/1.1.3/compojure-1.1.3.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.incubator/0.1.0/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.0/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/clout/clout/1.0.1/clout-1.0.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.1.5/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.1/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/hiccup/hiccup/0.3.6/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ring/ring-devel/1.3.0/ring-devel-1.3.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/clj-stacktrace/0.2.7/clj-stacktrace-0.2.7.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ns-tracker/ns-tracker/0.2.2/ns-tracker-0.2.2.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.namespace/0.2.4/tools.namespace-0.2.4.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/java.classpath/0.2.2/java.classpath-0.2.2.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ring/ring-jetty-adapter/1.3.0/ring-jetty-adapter-1.3.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ring/ring-servlet/1.3.0/ring-servlet-1.3.0.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.6.13.v20130916/jetty-server-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/2.5.0.v201103041518/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/7.6.13.v20130916/jetty-continuation-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/7.6.13.v20130916/jetty-http-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/7.6.13.v20130916/jetty-io-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/7.6.13.v20130916/jetty-util-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/ring/ring-json/0.3.1/ring-json-0.3.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/cheshire/cheshire/5.3.1/cheshire-5.3.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.1/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile/2.3.1/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.3.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/tigris/tigris/0.1.1/tigris-0.1.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.logging/0.2.3/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/disruptor/disruptor/2.10.4/disruptor-2.10.4.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.1/log4j-api-2.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.1/log4j-core-2.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.6/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:
                /home/mjsax/.m2/repository/args4j/args4j/2.0.16/args4j-2.0.16.jar
    package.to.your.MainClass
```

Comment: java -Dstorm.jar="X:\abc\xyz\ppp\ooo\zzz\target\jarName.jar" -cp X:\abc\xyz\ppp\ooo\zzz\target\classes\:X:\abc\xyz\apache-storm-0.10.0-beta\lib\* z.x.c.mainClass

Comment: if i do this i get class not found exception for my main class

Comment: you know someone else had pointed that out to me earlier. but then, i am running my Eclipse in windows, so how does it work from there?

Comment: perfect ! i found everything i needed and was able to form the proper command :) thanks a lot for your help and support !

Comment: will do. at least now i know its not a windows issue. now that i can make it to work with java command, all i need to do is configure the storm jar command properly

Comment: sorry about rolling back the accept on the answer. unfortunately, it was not as easy as i thought to modify the storm jar to work just as the java execution worked. please find the entire stacktrace in the latest edit

Comment: Why not using simply "java jar" instead of "storm jar" ??

Comment: it says Error: Could not find or load main class jar

Comment: i did java -cp  jarName.jar mainClass and i got 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/spout/Scheme

Comment: Read my answer.... You need to issue the same command Eclipse issues... It is more complicated than your command. The classpath must contain much more libraries...

Comment: absolutely, as it needs to bundle all of the libraries that my maven project uses. but all of those jars should be already included in the bundled jar that i am trying to deploy. please look at the latest edit. i was able to run the jar with java command but i still get the same error. i believe that it has something to do with my storm setup, perhaps in my YAML file.

Comment: makes sense. note that when i download storm, i get a storm.cmd batch file along with a storm.py and storm.sh. is this not meant to perform all the functions of storm in a dos environment? also, any idea why the java -cp command works and throws the same exception as storm jar?

Comment: not on windows. i was finally able to get hold of a linux box and test it. works without a hitch on linux. i compared the commands that the python script was trying to execute, in both cases. there was clearly some weird formatting of the paths in windows environment. maybe thats what was throwing it off.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse as an IDE? Did you try to run the `java` command that your IDE uses? This should work on Windows command line... (I am just curious now ;))

Comment: yup, the eclipse command works as it translates to a java execution of the jar file. but the storm jar command or the storm.py jar command does not work. they both complain that the topology name exists

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax where can i add  JVM argument -Dstorm.jar=path\to\myJar.jar here my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327617/could-not-extract-resources?noredirect=1#comment56418129_34327617

Comment: Look into my answer. The flag you are asking for is part of the example code of the answers.