# How to pass jvm args to a storm application

Tags: apache-storm, jvm-arguments

I am working on a storm application and need to pass env & cloud info using vmargs.
Program args raises security issues, since I am setting those values using System.setproperty & properties file I can't use. Vmargs don't work with storm.
Any idea what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running storm in cluster mode on a remote machine.
In this case, storm suggests you to use the `storm jar` command.  It is true, that this by default accepts just a few arguments since it is internally using a python script that is calling java.

But it seems to be possible to start storm with a java command as well and pass command line commands to that - see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980005/13847890).

Answer (score 0):

Another method to pass some variables to topology is the environment variable substitution in a flux file and run

```
name: topo${ENV-YOURVAR}
```

when run in bash looks like:

```
export YOURVAR=test
storm jar yourtopo.jar org.apache.storm.flux.Flux yourtopo.flux -e
```

Flag `-e` tells storm to substitute environment variables in the flux file