# Cucumber-jvm CLI run Error

Tags: java, maven, jvm, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Has anyone tried running the Cucumber-jvm cli without using maven?
If I try to execute the below command I am getting this error:

```
java cucumber.api.cli.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

I even tried this:

```
java -cp "/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-
core/1.2.5/cucumber-core-
1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin-
2.12.2.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-
java/1.2.5/cucumber-java-
1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-
 deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar" cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

I am getting the same error.

Comment: You should check  "/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-
core/1.2.5/cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar" exist and contain this `Main` class.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502518/eclipse-export-running-configuration/2502638#2502638).