# Eclipse: How to Import VM Arg Variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, junit, vmargs

I use custom variables for VM args when running my unit tests.  Is there a way to export and import these from another Eclipse project?

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502518/eclipse-export-running-configuration

Comment: That exports the launch configs, but unfortunately does not include the variable definitions that would be referenced.

Comment: Where are your vars defined?

Comment: They appear to be stored in preferences/string substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string substitution is stored in preferences/string substitution.  I was able to export and import General/Preferences and the string variables were populated.

[image: Export Preferences]

[image: string substitution]